# Parse PDF shape data in python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing

I am trying to put together a script to fix PDFs a large number of PDFs that have been exported from Autocad via their DWG2PDF print driver.

When using this driver all SHX fonts are rendered as shape data instead of text data, they do however have a comment inserted into the PDF at the expected location with the expected text.

So far in my script I have got it to run through the PDF and insert hidden text on top of each section, with the text squashed to the size of the comment, this gets me 90% of the way and gives me a document that is searchable.

Unfortunately the sizing of the comment regions is relatively course (integer based) which makes it difficult to accurately determine the orientation of short text, and results in uneven sized boxes around text.

What I would like to be able to do is parse through the shape data in the PDF, collect anything within the bounds of the comment, and then determine a smaller and more accurate bounding box. However all the information I can find is by people trying to parse through text data, and I haven't been able to find anything at all in terms of shape data.

The below image is an example of the raw text in the PDF, the second image shows the comment bounding box in blue, with the red text being what I am setting to hidden to make the document searchable, and copy/paste able. I can get things a little better by shrinking the box by a fixed margin, but with small text items the low resolution of the comment box coordinate data messes things up.

[image: Progress Image]

To get this far I am using a combination of PyPDF2 and reportlab, but am open to moving to different libraries.

Comment: I haven't looked too hard yet into picking a font with similar spacing to the fonts used in the drawings (typically isocp). Since the overlay is going to be hidden, the exact letter isn't too important to me but I do want to get the sizing closer so It visually looks better when doing things like searches that highlight all matching text.

Comment: I managed to get further with pdfminer, and am able to find all line and curve objects within a bounding box and use that to determine a better fitting bounding box. However in pdfminer I cant easily extract annotations meaning I will probably need to have some hybrid solution that pulls annotations with PyDF2 and then works through the shape data from pdfminer. I will have a play around tonight and will post an answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hi @Hugoagogo. I've been searching the ways on how to convert AutoCAD SHX Text to searchable text in PDF. I haven't figured out yet what to do. I am a beginner in Python. Would you like to share how did you accomplish it and what libraries did you used? I'm having a difficulty on how to loop within the pages and get the annotations to convert to searchable text and create a new PDF file then input all the content from the original PDF with searchable text in exact locations.

Comment: I will need to check with the boss tomorrow if I can share the code I produced, but I got my first start from a blog I found. https://niqiu.livejournal.com/153083.html?utm_source=3userpost I then look at each annotation in the pdf, and loop over all the shape data on the page to shrink the bounding box of the annotation to fit the shape data. I use this to apply a transformation/distortion to the text so that it aligns nicely.

Comment: Hi @Hugoagogo. Thanks for replying. I am still working on with the codes. I am able to get the text from the annotation but it is displayed in 90 degrees and not properly placed in the actual location of annotation. The output is only 1 page which is the last page of my PDF file (15 pages). Any suggestion on how do I get all the pages and merge it?

Comment: I cant offer my code at the moment unfortunately, in terms of the orientation I solved that by adding the text to the PDF, and then looking at its size compared to the bounding box of the annotation. I then rotated the text as needed to make the aspect ratios match (note this will only really work for two orientations of text which was good enough in my case). See the link in my previous comment about getting the comment bounding boxes. In terms of working through multiple pages, I just loop over the pages property of PdfFileWriter.

Comment: I managed to merge the pages. My problem now is that the converted text is not properly placed on top of the annotation and it is oriented in 90 degrees.

Comment: Hi @Hugoagogo. May I ask what are the libraries did you used?

Comment: PyPdf2 for reading the comments, and saving the output pdf. Pdfminer for looping over the shape data and reportlab to help overlaying the invisible text.

Comment: I'm having a difficulty on how to get the exact location for the text to be placed. Can you teach me in the part of looping the shape data for the specific object (selected annotation). I tried to do this while in the loop of the object but I can't get the correct concept/codes. The only problem in my codes is that the converted text is oriented in 90 degrees. I already created a question [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555941/convert-autocad-shx-text-to-searchable-text-in-pdf-using-python). I have no specific answers yet. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't end up finding a solution with PyPDF2, I was able to find an easy way to iterate over shape data in pdfminer.six, but then couldn't find a nice way in pdfminer to extract annotation data.

As such I am using one library to get the annotations, one to look at the shape data, and last of all a third library to add the hidden text on the new pdf. It runs pretty slowly as sheet complexity increases but is giving me good enough results, see image below where the rough green borders as found in the annotations are shrunk to the blue borders surrounding the text. Of course I don't draw the boundaries, and use invisible text for the actual program output, giving pretty good selectable/searchable text.

[image: example of output]

If anyone is interested in looping over the shape data in PDFs the below snippet should get you started.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTLine, LTCurve

for page_layout in extract_pages("TestSchem.pdf"):
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTCurve) or isinstance(element, LTLine):
            print(element.bbox)
```