# Convert AutoCAD SHX Text to searchable text in PDF using Python

Tags: python, reportlab, pypdf, pdf-parsing

PDF with **AutoCAD SHX Text** cannot be searched. We have a PDF files with annotation. My goal is to convert all AutoCAD SHX Text from PDF into text to be able to search it. I found [Convert AutoCAD SHX PDF annotation into searchable PDF](https://niqiu.livejournal.com/153083.html?utm_source=3userpost) that shows how to convert annotation to text.

However, I cannot get the exact location to place the converted text at the top of annotation and it is oriented in 90 degrees to the original text. I am able to get all the pages with contents and merge them to a new PDF file.

Here is my code

```
import io,os
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from datetime import date, time, datetime,timedelta

def convert_annot(pdf_name):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_name, "rb"))
    numPages = pdf.getNumPages()
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    # Loop to pages
    for i in range(0, numPages):
        page = pdf.getPage(i) 
        objs=[]
        try :
            for annot in page['/Annots']:
                obj=annot.getObject()
                if 'AutoCAD SHX Text' in obj.values():
                    print (obj['/Contents'],obj['/Rect'])
                    objs.append(obj)
        
            page_size=pdf.getPage(0).mediaBox.upperRight
            w, h =page_size
            packet = io.BytesIO()
            c = canvas.Canvas(packet,pagesize=landscape(A4))
            c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold',12)
            c.setFillColor(colors.red)
            for obj in objs:
                if '/Contents' in obj:
                    xy=tuple(obj['/Rect'])
                    llx,lly,urx,ury=xy   #LowerLeftX,LowerLeftY,UpperRightX, UpperRightY
                    text=obj['/Contents']
                    x1=int(urx)
                    y1=int(lly)
                    c.drawString(x1,y1,text)
            c.save()

            #buffer start from 0
            packet.seek(0)
            new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
            page=None
            new_pdf_file_name=None

            #read existing pdf
            page = pdf.pages[i]
            page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
            output.add_page(page)
        except :
            page_size=pdf.getPage(0).mediaBox.upperRight
            w, h =page_size
            packet = io.BytesIO()
            c = canvas.Canvas(packet,pagesize=landscape(A4))
            c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold',12)
            c.setFillColor(colors.red)
            for obj in objs:
                if '/Contents' in obj:
                    xy=tuple(obj['/Rect'])
                    llx,lly,urx,ury=xy   #LowerLeftX,LowerLeftY,UpperRightX, UpperRightY
                    text=obj['/Contents']
                    x1=int(urx)
                    y1=int(lly)
                    c.drawString(x1,y1,text)
            c.save()
            #buffer start from 0
            packet.seek(0)
            new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
            page=None
            new_pdf_file_name=None
            #read existing pdf
            page = pdf.pages[i]
            page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
            output.add_page(page)

    # Finally output new pdf
    new_pdf_file_name=os.path.splitext(pdf_name)[0]+".annot.pdf"
    outputStream = open(new_pdf_file_name, "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_name='samplePdf.pdf'
    convert_annot(pdf_name)
```

Sample PDF with annotation (cannot be selected or search):

[image]

Output result:

[image]

The text **NOTES** (red color) is not placed exactly in the position of the text **NOTES** (black color | AutoCAD SHX Text).

I am new to Python. I am trying to get the exact location of annotation so that I can place to it the converted text. I'm still thinking a way on how do it by using **PdfMiner** to get the coordinates. The problem is I don't know how can I use it inside the loop of the **object** (selected AutoCAD SHX Text annotation in a page) so that every object will have an exact coordinates for placing the converted text.

Expected result should be:

[image]

Any idea or concept for getting the location (using PdfMiner) of the specific converted text is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @K J. We have PDF files that contains "AutoCAD SHX Text" annotation. The users cannot search within the PDF because the annotation cannot be selected/search. I am able to convert it into searchable text and extract the contents with converted text to a new PDF file. But the problem is that the converted text is not placed exactly where the annotation is located. I've been working on how to get the exact coordinates of annotation and the exact size of font using PdfMiner but I am not able to apply it within the loop of objects (selected annotations).

Comment: How are you able to read this file ? I can't even extract text!